# SD Card as ADOPTABLE STORAGE isn’t recognised anymore

Tags: adoptable-storage

***Hello EXPERTS,***
I have somehow messed up my phone and require some help to get it back working as many information and data are suddenly not available anymore.
Before someone tries to explain me the importance of a backup, so be assured, that I run backups regularly, however since my storage was full and I didn’t purchase more of it, some data wasn’t backedup.

This is my situation and I would really need some „positive motivating feedback“:

1. I use a SAMSUNG GALAXY S7 rooted with NOUGAT 7.0
2. I use a 256 GB SD card formatted as adoptable storage
3. two days ago, I wanted to copy some data to a colleague and inserted his SD card, which was formatted as portable storage into my device. I copied the 2 large PowerPoint Presentations and when I swapped the SD cards again, my phone didn’t recognise anylonger my own SD card.
4. A message: „Unsupported SD card“ is shown and „This device doesn’t support this SD card. Tap to set u...“
5. The swap of the SD cards was done while the phone was powered off and on again.
6. Let’s assume please, that the SD card is undamaged and that nothing happened to it while it was removed around 10 min from my device.
7. My phone still has some data available and I am not taking at this stage any pictures or installing any apps. So all key information about the adoptable storage should still be on the device and on the SD card.

Please let me know the steps, how I can connect again my SD card to my phone, allowing my phone to recognise my SD card again as his adoptable drive without that I need to format it and loose data, which is not included since the last backup.

***Thanks a lot!***
Gino